# Python 2 readline issue

Tags: python, graph-theory

I'm trying to build some discrete optimization algorithm (to build djisktra, flowd warshall and bellman ford), and i built it in python3, but actually i need it in python2, and there problems come...

here is my code :

```
import os.path

def dict_fromFile():
    fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'metroEdgeDist.txt')
    f = open(fn, 'r')
    i=0
    dict_voisins = {}
    nb_sommets = f.readline()
    list_temp = {}
    for line in f:
        nb_voisins = line
        for nb in range(0,int(nb_voisins)):
            tempSommet = f.readline()
            tempPoids = f.readline()
            list_temp.update({int(tempSommet.replace("\n","")):float(tempPoids.replace("\n",""))})
        dict_voisins[i]= list_temp
        list_temp = {}
        i+=1
    f.close()
    return dict_voisins

def mat_fromFile():
    fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'metroEdgeDist.txt')
    f = open(fn, 'r')
    i=0
    nb_sommets = int(f.readline())
    mat_voisins = [[ float('inf') for i in range(nb_sommets) ] for j in range(nb_sommets) ]
    for line in f:
        nb_voisins = line
        for nb in range(0,int(nb_voisins)):
            tempSommet = f.readline()
            tempPoids = f.readline()
            mat_voisins[i][int(tempSommet.replace("\n",""))] = float(tempPoids.replace("\n",""))
        mat_voisins[i][i]=0 
        i+=1
    f.close()
    return mat_voisins
```

So the trouble is **"Mixing iterations"**... but actually i don't know how different to do so...

The thing is i need those "readline()" in the for loop, because the i'm trying to read the 2 lines and store them in variables...

The code is the one i use to actually create my adjacency matrix and my dictionary from the input
The input data is of the form:

```
304 #total number of vertex
1 #vertex number 0 has 1 neighbor
1 #the 1st neighbor o 0 is 1
1.067 # the value of the edge bteween 0 & 1 is 1.067
2 #vertex number 1 has 2 neighbors
0 #first neighbor is vertex 0
1.067 #value of edge is 1.067
2 #second neighbor is vertex 2
0.848 #value of edge is 0.848
2 #vertex 2 has 2 neighbors ...
1
0.848
```

So if you think of a better way to read the file or how to correct my mixing iterations issue !!

Thanks a loooooot guys !!

Comment: Don't understand what your problem is, exactly.

Comment: "Mixing iteration"--> readline in a loop, i've solved it before but in that case i don't know how to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:
1) a while loop with all 3 readlines inside

2) you keep the for loop and you use a variable (or two) to remember at which stage you are